# How does the disengage action work against a monster with the reactive heads ability, such as a hydra?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, rogue, opportunity-attack

I was DMing a session with a group of friends when this situation occurred. One of the PCs was near a hydra and he used his bonus action to disengage from it after attacking it. He can do so because of his rogue ability called cunning action.

How do opportunity attacks work for a monster like the hydra? The hydra has an ability called Reactive Heads which makes it use as many reactions as it has heads. The hydra had 4 heads at the time. I don't understand how it works in this situation. Does the rogue get away safely even though the hydra has more than 1 reaction? How does the disengage action work against a hydra or any monster with the reactive heads ability?

Answer (score 21):

### Disengage prevents the opportunity attack

The rules on disengaging can be found on page 192 under *Actions in Combat* in the Player's handbook.

> If you take the Disengage action, your movement doesn't
>   provoke opportunity attacks for the rest of the turn.

That's it - no matter how many reactions the hydra has left, it can't use them to opportunity attack a disengaging creature. The increased number of reactions only allows the hydra to make more opportunity attacks per round, but doesn't otherwise give it extra liberty with them.